# Differences in ownership rules between PyDict_SetItem vs. PyList_SetItem or PyTuple_SetItem?

Tags: cpython

Two questions about ownership rules and reference counts using functions in CPython like PyDict_SetItem and PyList_SetItem:

1. I would appreciate it if someone could explain why PyDict_SetItem does not take ownership of the passed in value, while PyList_SetItem and PyTuple_SetItem do?  Here's the passage from CPython docs that notes this difference:

> When you pass an object reference into another function, in general,
>   the function borrows the reference from you — if it needs to store it,
>   it will use Py_INCREF() to become an independent owner. There are
>   exactly two important exceptions to this rule: PyTuple_SetItem() and
>   PyList_SetItem(). These functions take over ownership of the item
>   passed to them — even if they fail! (Note that PyDict_SetItem() and
>   friends don’t take over ownership — they are “normal.”)

Is this somehow logical (which would make it easier to internalize and remember) or is it mostly just a random historical artifact of a design decision made long ago?

2. Also, just to make sure I understand - the statement that PyDict_SetItem "does not take ownership of the reference" means that it calls Py_INCREF on the value that I pass in internally, right?  ie- In most cases I would need to call Py_DECREF on the value soon after calling PyDict_SetItem (like what is done in the code in this stackoverflow question: [Reference counting using PyDict_SetItemString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700251/reference-counting-using-pydict-setitemstring/41320615#41320615))?
   Thanks.